# Don't open connection if not needed

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony with Doctrine. I use memcached. In some cases when results from DB are cached, there is no need to open a connection with Database. But Doctrine does it anyway. Is there a possibility no to open DB connection if there is no DB Query?

Comment: What do you mean by a connection? A MySQL connection? How do you know there is a connection?

Comment: @StephanVierkant  yes, I meant MySQL connection. I used Blackfire.io to track bottle necks and in recommendations I found that the connection is being established by doctrine but there are no queries that are actually executed. Therefore, connecting to the database server introduces some overhead due to the TCP/IP connection.

Comment: Can you create a reproducable example? If you really don't need a connection and it still creates one, this should be fixed in Symfony, not in your application.

Comment: Hi @Tom, where you able to figure this out? I’m having the a similar problem.

Comment: No, unfortunately.